# slow performance with select query on postgresql remote fdw table

Tags: postgresql, foreign-data-wrapper

I have 2 postgresql instances on different computers(X and Y) on the same network.
Y server has PgAdmin installed on and connected to both instances.

On the Y instance, I created FDW connection for a database on X.

My problem is It takes over 30 seconds when I run a select query over foreign table.
If I run the same query into direct to X server from PgAdmin, it takes under 1 sec and I though the reason for slow performance couldn't be the network issue.

I tried both with `on` and `off` for `use_remote_estimate` but since my foreign table keeps updating with new data continuously, I decided to keep it `off`.

My query is below

```
SELECT q_num,
    count(*)::integer AS total_calls,
    count(1) FILTER (WHERE na_code = 0 AND fail_code = 0)::integer AS answered,
    count(1) FILTER (WHERE na_code = 0 AND fail_code = 0 AND (wait + poll) <= '00:00:15'::interval)::integer AS answered_15,
    count(1) FILTER (WHERE na_code = 0 AND fail_code = 0 AND (wait + poll) <= '00:00:20'::interval)::integer AS answered_20,
    count(1) FILTER (WHERE na_code = 0 AND fail_code = 0 AND (wait + poll) <= '00:00:30'::interval)::integer AS answered_30,
    count(1) FILTER (WHERE na_code <> 0 OR fail_code <> 0)::integer AS missed,
    count(1) FILTER (WHERE na_code <> 0 OR fail_code <> 0 AND (wait + poll) > '00:00:15'::interval)::integer AS missed_15,
    count(1) FILTER (WHERE na_code <> 0 OR fail_code <> 0 AND (wait + poll) > '00:00:20'::interval)::integer AS missed_20,
    count(1) FILTER (WHERE na_code <> 0 OR fail_code <> 0 AND (wait + poll) > '00:00:30'::interval)::integer AS missed_30,
    EXTRACT(epoch FROM sum(wait + poll))::integer AS total_waiting,
    EXTRACT(epoch FROM max(wait + poll))::integer AS max_waiting
FROM foreign_table
WHERE time_start > (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - '03:15:00'::interval)
GROUP BY q_num
```

`time_start` column has index on the remote server.

How can I improve the performance?

EDIT:
Just tried to increase fetch_size but it still takes more than 20 seconds.

@Frank Heikens
Here is the index

```
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS original_table_time_start_idx
    ON public.original_table USING btree
    (time_start ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

Postgresql version on X instance

> PostgreSQL 11.9, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit

Postgresql version on Y instance

> PostgreSQL 14.5, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit

EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) on X instance

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=8.51..8.91 rows=2 width=49) (actual time=0.148..0.150 rows=1 loops=1)    
Output: q_num, (count(*))::integer, (count(1) FILTER (WHERE ((na_code = 0) AND (fail_code = 0))))::integer, (count(1) FILTER (WHERE ((na_code = 0) AND (fail_code = 0) AND ((wait + poll) <= '00:00:15'::interval))))::integer, (count(1) FILTER (WHERE ((na_code = 0) AND (fail_code = 0) AND ((wait + poll) <= '00:00:20'::interval))))::integer, (count(1) FILTER (WHERE ((na_code = 0) AND (fail_code = 0) AND ((wait + poll) <= '00:00:30'::interval))))::integer, (count(1) FILTER (WHERE ((na_code <> 0) OR (fail_code <> 0))))::integer, (count(1) FILTER (WHERE ((na_code <> 0) OR ((fail_code <> 0) AND ((wait + poll) > '00:00:15'::interval)))))::integer, (count(1) FILTER (WHERE ((na_code <> 0) OR ((fail_code <> 0) AND ((wait + poll) > '00:00:20'::interval)))))::integer, (count(1) FILTER (WHERE ((na_code <> 0) OR ((fail_code <> 0) AND ((wait + poll) > '00:00:30'::interval)))))::integer, (date_part('epoch'::text, sum((wait + poll))))::integer, (date_part('epoch'::text, max((wait + poll))))::integer
Group Key: original_table.q_num    
Buffers: shared hit=4   
->  Sort (cost=8.51..8.51 rows=3 width=45) (actual time=0.099..0.101 rows=3 loops=1) 
Output: q_num, na_code, fail_code, wait, poll 
Sort Key: original_table.q_num 
Sort Method: quicksort  
Memory: 25kB 
Buffers: shared hit=4
->  Index Scan using original_table_time_start_idx on public.original_table  (cost=0.43..8.48 rows=3 width=45) (actual time=0.052..0.060 rows=3 loops=1) 
Output: q_num, na_code, fail_code, wait, poll 
Index Cond: (original_table.time_start > (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - '00:15:00'::interval)) 
Buffers: shared hit=4 
Planning Time: 1.383 ms 
Execution Time: 0.638 ms
```

EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) on Y instance

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=48287.41..48295.41 rows=6 width=49) (actual time=22846.842..22846.847 rows=1 loops=1)   
Output: q_num, (count(*))::integer, (count(1) FILTER (WHERE ((na_code = 0) AND (fail_code = 0))))::integer, (count(1) FILTER (WHERE ((na_code = 0) AND (fail_code = 0) AND ((wait + poll) <= '00:00:15'::interval))))::integer, (count(1) FILTER (WHERE ((na_code = 0) AND (fail_code = 0) AND ((wait + poll) <= '00:00:20'::interval))))::integer, (count(1) FILTER (WHERE ((na_code = 0) AND (fail_code = 0) AND ((wait + poll) <= '00:00:30'::interval))))::integer, (count(1) FILTER (WHERE ((na_code <> 0) OR (fail_code <> 0))))::integer, (count(1) FILTER (WHERE ((na_code <> 0) OR ((fail_code <> 0) AND ((wait + poll) > '00:00:15'::interval)))))::integer, (count(1) FILTER (WHERE ((na_code <> 0) OR ((fail_code <> 0) AND ((wait + poll) > '00:00:20'::interval)))))::integer, (count(1) FILTER (WHERE ((na_code <> 0) OR ((fail_code <> 0) AND ((wait + poll) > '00:00:30'::interval)))))::integer, (EXTRACT(epoch FROM sum((wait + poll))))::integer, (EXTRACT(epoch FROM max((wait + poll))))::integer
Group Key: foreign_table.q_num   
->  Sort  (cost=48287.41..48287.59 rows=72 width=45) (actual time=22846.755..22846.759 rows=1 loops=1)
Output: q_num, na_code, fail_code, wait, poll
Sort Key: foreign_table.q_num
Sort Method: quicksort  
Memory: 25kB
->  Foreign Scan on public.foreign_table  (cost=100.00..48285.19 rows=72 width=45) (actual time=10927.554..22846.717 rows=1 loops=1)
Output: q_num, na_code, fail_code, wait, poll
Filter: (foreign_table.time_start > (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - '03:15:00'::interval))
Rows Removed by Filter: 720077
Remote SQL: SELECT q_num, time_start, wait, poll, na_code, fail_code FROM public.original_table 
Planning Time: 0.522 ms 
Execution Time: 22849.716 ms
```

I hope these informations helps.

Comment: What PostgreSQL versions do you have? And could you please share the results from explain (analyze, verbose, buffers) for this statement? In plain text please. And if possible, also the results when you execute this query directly on the remote server, using the original table. And could you please share the ddl from this table and it’s indexes?

Comment: a combined index on (na_code  fail_code wait  poll) would be a good start, maybe even one combined with time_start

Comment: Without the results of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, VERBOSE)`, it's difficult to gain much insight into the query's behavior. I suggest turning `use_remote_estimate` back on since without it the local DB doesn't have much ability to optimize the query. There might also be some performance gain from increasing the fetch size from the default of 100 rows.

Comment: @FrankHeikens just added all the informations.

Comment: @JohnH use_remote_estimate option is not make any difference. remote table has over 700k record. fetch size is 1000 now. I though it would be enough because when this query runs, it works on last 15 minutes data and it would definetly be under 1000.

Comment: Create a view on the source database and create a new foreign table using this view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

expressions using CURRENT_TIMESTAMP are not considered shippable to the foreign side.  You could argue that it should be shippable, as you could just materialize it into a literal and then ship the literal, but that is now how it currently works.  So instead all rows need to be read back and have their timestamps tested locally.

> EDIT: Just tried to increase fetch_size but it still takes more than 20 seconds.

What did you increase it to?  Maybe increase it yet more.